# При скролле пропадает маркер и выскакивает ошибка?

Tags: vue.js, yandex-maps-api

Есть компонент

```
<script setup lang="ts">
      import _ from 'lodash';
      import { onMounted, ref, defineProps, PropType, watch } from 'vue';
      import { YM_DEFAULT_CENTER } from '@/shared/constants';
    
      const emits = defineEmits(['click']);
    
      const props = defineProps({
        location: {
          type: Array as PropType<number[]>,
          default: YM_DEFAULT_CENTER,
        },
      });
    
      const mapCenter = ref(YM_DEFAULT_CENTER);
      const map = ref();
      const marker = ref();
    
      function initMap() {
        ymaps.ready(() => {
          map.value = new ymaps.Map(
            'map',
            {
              center: mapCenter.value,
              zoom: 14,
            },
            {
              suppressMapOpenBlock: true,
              suppressObsoleteBrowserNotifier: true,
            }
          );
    
          map.value.events.add('click', (e: any) => {
            console.log(e.get('coords'));
            emits('click', e.get('coords'));
          });
        });
      }
    
      function setCenter(center: any, zoom = null) {
        mapCenter.value = center;
        ymaps.ready(() => {
          map.value && map.value.setCenter(center);
          if (zoom) {
            map.value && map.value.setZoom(zoom);
          }
        });
      }
    
      function _setMarker(location: number[]) {
        if (!location[0] || !location[1]) {
          return false;
        }
        ymaps.ready(() => {
          if (!marker.value) {
            marker.value = new ymaps.Placemark(location);
            marker.value.name = 'Ваше местоположение';
            map.value.geoObjects.add(marker.value);
          } else {
            marker.value.geometry.setCoordinates(location);
          }
        });
        setCenter(location);
        return true;
      }
    
      watch(
        props.location,
        _.debounce(() => _setMarker(props.location), 100),
        { immediate: true }
      );
    
      onMounted(() => {
        initMap();
      });
    </script>
    
    <template>
      <div class="map-container">
        <div
          id="map"
          class="w-full h-96"
          ref="map"></div>
      </div>
    </template>
```

при скролле на карте выскакивает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]